# Можете , пожалуйста , объяснить , что в данном контексте означает S obs?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, случайные-числа, статистика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что в данном случае такое S obs и почему оно задается именно таким образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то формулы - из матстатистики [для выборочного среднего](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5) - если дисперсия конечна и ненулевая, то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. отклонение среднего, умноженное на квадратный корень из `n`, имеет нормальное распределение. В нашем случае ожидаемое среднее - 0, так что нормальное распределение имеет величина среднего выборки, умноженного на корень из `n`. А так как среднее - сумма элементов, деленная на `n`, то в нашем случае для получения нормально распределенной величины надо сумму поделить на корень из `n`.

Вот и все. Ну, а что конкретно значит `obs`... Подозреваю - observed (наблюдаемый)...

Comment: окей, спасибо большое